# Java: Reflection, Generic Types, and Unchecked Casts

Tags: java, generics, reflection

My class will be given an Object class. I am then using reflection to iterate over the declared fields of that class and registering a `ChangeListener` on each field with the `Property` base class.

The original 'createChangeListener' method looked like this:

```
private void createChangeListener(Property property) {
    property.addListener(new ChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void changed(ObservableValue observable, Object oldValue, Object newValue) {                        
            Foo.this.propertyChanged(observable);
        }
    });
}
```

However, this was producing an unwanted warning:

```
warning: [unchecked] unchecked call to addListener(ChangeListener<? super T>) as a member of the raw type ObservableValue
    property.addListener(new ChangeListener() {
        where T is a type-variable:
    T extends Object declared in interface ObservableValue
```

Not to be dissuaded, I provided a generic type for my `Property` parameter and `ChangeListener`:

```
private void createChangeListener(Property<Object> property) {
    property.addListener(new ChangeListener<Object>() {
        @Override
        public void changed(ObservableValue observable, Object oldValue, Object newValue) {                        
            Foo.this.propertyChanged(observable);
        }
    });
}
```

...Only now to be notified that I have simply shifted my problem to the source of the reflection. The code, below, is now modified to cast to `Property<Object>` from its original `Property` w/o a generic type:

```
if (Property.class.isAssignableFrom(field.getType())) {
    createChangeListener((Property<Object>)(field.get(model)));
}
```

This previously warningless code is now producing the head-tilting:

```
warning: [unchecked] unchecked cast
    createChangeListener((Property<Object>)(field.get(model)));
required: Property<Object>
found:    Object
```

Questions:

- ಠ_ಠ
- Given Java's type erasure limitations, what techniques are available to me to safely resolve these warnings?
- Am I safe to suppress the unchecked warning in the original, non-typed method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to ramp up your generics skills.

Instead of trying to solve it by *casts*, try solving it by writing *generic* code yourself:

```
private <T> void createChangeListener(Property<T> property) {
  property.addListener(new ChangeListener<T>() {
    @Override
    public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends T> observable, T oldValue, T newValue) {                        
        Foo.this.propertyChanged(observable);
    }
  });
}
```

Here, the **compiler can help you with type checking**. It knows that oldValue and newValue will have a certain type T, and can check that you do not make incorrect assumptions.

Now since `addListener(ChangeListener<? super T>)` will also accept listeners for *super types* (`<? super T>`!), the following should be fine, too:

```
private void createChangeListener(Property<?> property) {
  property.addListener(new ChangeListener<Object>() {
    @Override
    public void changed(ObservableValue<?> observable, Object oldValue, Object newValue) {                        
        Foo.this.propertyChanged(observable);
    }
  });
}
```

The compiler should be able to verify that this code is *type safe*.

Make sure you know the differences between `<?>`, `<Object>`, `<T>`, `<? super T>`, `<? extends T>` and try to learn how to use them in your own code. Always prefer the *broader* version (`extends` and `super` can make all the difference! Check the Java Collections for examples).

In above example, the `super` means that you are allowed to attach an `Object` listener to a `Property<String>`, because it is a supertype of `String`.

Comment: Thank you! You have diagnosed a solution and the root cause: my lack of generics knowledge. While both answers so far have answered the question, this one may have the highest chance of helping someone in the future. Have a great day!

Answer (score 2):

Casting your field value to `Property<Object>` you say explicitly that `Property` generic parameter is `Object`, which may be wrong and compiler cannot help you. For example, the real type of the field is `Property<String>` you may do the following:

```
Property<Object> p = (Property<Object>)(field.get(model)); // compiler warning, runtime ok
p.setValue(new Object()); // runtime ok, but now you're probably stored incompatible value

// somewhere much later in completely different piece of code
String value = this.propertyField.getValue(); // sudden ClassCastException
```

So compiler warns you that casting to `Property<Object>` you are making an assumption the compiler cannot prove and you may have actually different type which may result in putting the object into incorrect state which may break your program somewhere much later.

In your particular case you don't want to say "I know that generic argument type is an `Object`". What do you want to say is "I don't care about generic argument type". For this case there's a special construct `<?>`. You can use it here:

```
void createChangeListener(Property<?> property) {
    property.addListener(new ChangeListener<Object>() {
        @Override
        public void changed(ObservableValue<?> observable, 
                            Object oldValue, Object newValue) {                        
            Foo.this.propertyChanged(observable);
        }
    });
}
```

And you can safely cast to `Property<?>` without any warning. Now however you cannot call `setValue` at all, but seems that you don't need anyways.

Comment: Thank you! This is very informative. I will need to carefully consider the setValue limitation and proceed carefully.